# What is the event identifier in Neura?

Tags: android, ios, sdk, webhooks, neura

I am using the Neura SDK, and trying to receive the events through a webhook. Its asking me for an event identifier.And also it's not letting me subscribe to events. where do i find an event identifier?

Answer (score 3):

The event identifier will be part of the data sent to your webhook when Neura identifies an event for this subscription. It's there for you to attach a user identification, for example. The webhook identifier is the one you gave while registering the app.

You can find more details about Event Identifier and Neura API Client [here](http://docs.theneura.com/android/com/neura/standalonesdk/service/NeuraApiClient.html)